# show the second "page" of ajax fetched html document

Tags: jquery-mobile

I have a first page called index.html, where i have two links "red fruits" and "yellow fruits".

Then i have "fruits.html" which has two jquery pages with id "redFruits", "yellowFruits".

When somebody clicks "yellow fruits" link on the index.html i need to show the second "page" of the fruits.html. By default, jquery mobile shows the first page of the "fruits.html".

Any idea of how to link to random page of the ajax fetched document.

**"index.html"**

```
<div data-role="content">
        <a href="fruitsList.html" data-role="button">List of red fruits</a>
        <a href="fruitsList.html" data-role="button">List of yellow fruits</a>
    </div>
```

**fruits.html**

```
....
<div data-role="page" id="redFruits">
....
       <p data-role="content">
        <ul>
            <li>apple 1</li>
            <li>apple 2</li>
            <li>apple 3</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
.....
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="yellowFruits">
    .....
    <p data-role="content">
        <ul>
            <li>lemon</li>
            <li>papaya</li>
            <li>yellow fig</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
         .....
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reference the sub pages within a multiple pages document via hash tags:

```
<a href="fruitsList.html#redFruits" rel="external" data-role="button">List of red fruits</a>
<a href="fruitsList.html#yellowFruits" rel="external" data-role="button">List of yellow fruits</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, add the `rel="external"` to the anchor tag. Also, you use a `<p>` tag for your `data-role="content"` which looks technically correct but it is a bit unconventional. Consider using a `<div>` instead.

Comment: The same problem but, i tried to programatically change the page using changePage method instead of giving the url in the anchor tag but its not working..

`<a href="#" data-role="button" rel="external" id="redFruitsBtn">List of red fruits</a>

$("#redFruitsBtn").click(function(){
   $.mobile.changePage("fruitsList.html#redFruits", {transition: "fade" });
  })`

Its landing to the "first page" of the `fruitsList.html`. which is yellow fruits list.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`pageparams`](https://github.com/jblas/jquery-mobile-plugins/tree/master/page-params) plugin to send data to the second page - in this case an `#id` of the page to be displayed. 
In the `pagebeforeshow` of `page2` you can check for the param passed and `changePage()` accordingly.